# Dropdown/Radio button as an action selection in a grid row?

Tags: responsive-design, dropdown, selection, grid, radio-buttons

I need to display an action selection in every row of a grid. The action could be Do nothing, Confirm, Reject (mutually exclusive). And once all the selections were made, users are expected to hit a submit button to send the data. Which control is best for this? A dropdown and radio button comes to my mind but I do not like either solution. Dropdown is a two-click selection for every row and not very mobile friendly, radio button seems to make the page cluttered (too much repetition of the options). I was wondering if there is any other way. If no other suggestions, which one would you use? Thanks.

Comment: are they supposed to hit submit after each and every action?

Comment: What is the wort case scenario for number of rows in the grid, need to consider this for best design.

Comment: They are supposed to hit submit after they make selections for all rows (i.e. not after each row selection). And number of rows would be low, less than 10

Answer (score 2):

Case 1:- Grid with few rows (<10)
    Show radio buttons always instead of combo(repetition is not a big deal with few rows).

Case 2:- Grid with several rows (>10)
    Show radio buttons on mouseover only(to avoid repetition), otherwise by default show selected action in that column.

Combo is not a good choice for following reasons:-

1. Need to click combo trigger to know all options.
2. Need at least two click to select an option.

Combo's are better over radiobuttons in case where options are more than 3.

Comment: Also note that radio buttons can be styled to look like a segmented control. That will make it easier to glance at the table and see which rows were confirmed or rejected without having to squint to see the tiny radio dot filled in.

Answer (score 0):

- If the number of selection options (Yes, No & Undecided) are the only
  ones or to **the max if the options increase to 5** the following
  approach is feasible.
- Herein you want such a control in a grid and that too for every row
  wherein numerous other controls and values will be displayed.
- In such a scenario using a "**Drop-down**" for the same will be an ideal
  solution.Two click selection is not an issue
- Viewing up to 5 options in a drop-down is fine but, if it exceeds that
  with a great number then it may lead to an inconvenient user experience.
- So, **consider the number of options** you are to provide in the
  drop-down.
- Expecting the user to click on **Submit** after all selections are made
  is fine.